# What is the name of TV show or film about fake space ship or space station?

Tags: story-identification

I remember that the last scene of the show has the group of astronauts talking or arguing about something and they are surprised by the entrance of someone who was conducting the experiment on them shows up because they had thought they were in a spaceship or space station the whole time. Not sure if anyone in the group was in on the experiment.

Comment: When did you watch it? Also, check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: I remember this film, but not the name. There were 4 or 5 men, a claustrophobic setting, white walls. At least one of them lost it and started killing the others... sorry I cant help more.

Comment: There was one movie where people were sealed in a fake space station for experimenting purposes, to be released after predetermined time, but when the time came they were not released, and in the meantime some kind of worldwide disaster occured.

Comment: Shades of the first episode of the original _The Twilight Zone_: [Where Is Everybody?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_Is_Everybody%3F)

Comment: With the current description, I'd say the question is too vague. You're talking about the last scene of a show. Do you mean the last scene of an episode? Last scene of the last episode? Last episode of the show? And how large was the group, roughly? A handful? Over 20? Do you remember anyone's or anything's name?

Comment: Not related, but it reminded me of Asimov's [Ideas die hard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117028/13875)

Answer (score 28):

It could be [*Ascension*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascension_(miniseries)). This was a 2014/2015 miniseries. It was aired as either 6, 1 hour long episodes or 3 feature length instalments.

> The story takes place aboard a generation ship originally launched in the 1960s and now half-way into its 100-year journey to Proxima Centauri. A murder on board sparks off a series of events that leads the crew to begin second-guessing their real mission.

The Ascension is the titular spaceship. It has a large crew and strict birth control laws and dual military/civilian control hierarchy. A significant amount of tension exists between the Upper and Lower "Decks". One living a 1960s university campus life style, the other grease covered engineers and manual workers.

> At the end of the 1st double episode it's revealed that the spaceship never left Earth, it's parked in a basement somewhere, but it takes the whole rest of the series to unpack the real purpose behind the arrangement.

There are a couple of instances where people see things they're not expecting to. But for the most part everything is accepted at face value, the opening plot threads focusing on a murder committed on Ascension, with a gun that shouldn't be there.

> One person on board the spaceship was in on it. Everyone else genuinely believed they were on a generational interstellar spaceship.

Comment: And there was a Cylon on that ship too...

Comment: There was also one on Hawaii 5-0.  And Quantum Leap.  They're everywhere!

Comment: There was also one in ST:TOS I think where they wanted Cpt Kirk to pass on his illness(?) to a female alien aboard a fake Enterprise. No astronauts though. _Ascension_ seems right. I watched that and really enjoyed it.

Comment: Yeah, too bad about the unresolved ending.

Answer (score 12):

It could be the British series/reality show *Space Cadets* from 2005.
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Cadets_(TV_series)):

> Space Cadets is a British television programme made by Zeppotron (a division of Endemol UK) for Channel 4. Presented by Johnny Vaughan, it was aired across ten consecutive nights beginning on 7 December 2005, with the final episode aired on the evening of 16 December 2005.
>   
> The series was a hoax at the expense of its contestants, who were told they were being trained as cosmonauts at a Russian military base before undergoing a five-day trip into low earth orbit. In reality, the entire series was filmed in Suffolk, and the contestants did not leave Earth. The series was accompanied by a behind-the-scenes sister show Space Cadets: The Satellite Show, with interviews and phone-ins.